# RadAutoCompleteBox : remove highlight of first row

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, telerik

By default first row in telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox is always highlighted in a dark grey, how I can to remove this highlight?

My xalm code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox     WatermarkContent="Enter data"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                x:Name="companiesAutoCompleteBox"
                                TextSearchMode="StartsWith"
                                AutoCompleteMode="Suggest"
                                SelectionMode="Single"
                                TextSearchPath="Name"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
                                DropDownItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CompaniesSearchAutoComplete}"
                                SelectionChanged="dataAutoCompleteBoxSelectionChanged"
                                SearchTextChanged="dataSearchTextChanged" />
```